# Типизация массива, в котором все, кроме последнего - строки, последний элемент - функция. Typescript

Tags: typescript

У меня есть функция чтения файла `readFile`, в нее можно передавать несколько аргументов: `readFile('folder', 'target', e => console.error(e))`

Строковые аргументы - это путь до файла, последний аргумент - это функция обработки ошибок.

Выглядит функция вот так:

```
import * as p from 'path';

type ErrorHandler = (e: Error, path: string) => any | void;
type ReadFileParams = (Array<string> & ErrorHandler) | Array<string>;

export const readFile = (...params: ReadFileParams): object | null => {
  const source: Array<string> = params.filter(o => typeof o === 'string');
  const errorHandler =
    params.find(o => typeof o === 'function') ||
    ((e: Error) => {
      throw e;
    });
  const path = p.resolve(...source);
  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(data);
  } catch (e) {
    (<ErrorHandler>errorHandler)(e, path);
  }
  return null;
};
```

Пока я вызываю только со строковыми аргументами - ts не ругается.

Как только передаю последним аргументом функцию, например:

```
readFile(source, files[0].name, () => {});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводится вот такое сообщение об ошибке:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '[string, string, () => void]' is not
assignable to parameter of type 'ReadFileParams'.   
Type '[string, string, () => void]' is not assignable 
to type 'string[] & ErrorHandler'.     
Type '[string, string, () => void]' is not assignable 
to type 'string[]'.
Type 'string | (() => void)' is not assignable 
to type 'string'.         
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Как правильно описать типы в данной ситуации?

Comment: Думаю, тебе надо определить `type ReadFileParams = (ErrorHandler | Array<string>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5zHAZlCI4DkYyMAFgQNwBQoksiK6WTu+BzlVXMAnmAKZwAolFxQAEsgB2AEwA2-KHAC8cABT8AXMNHQANBhKltqGFGBSA5gEoVAPhRSecAD5wAbhGAzqvAXAAlfmQZADFgBQAFZChkEHRVAG1TcysDFItLAxExSVkFKABdaioAYwgpUzhgVABlM0yVdQBHEwarV0cea21m6vQMjuU7KjgxwkSIACMAK35S+HrUy0KCFWVVAHlZ+ZgAOjBcGAg-fj3jpcy90uQ5OTVm62oAeme4csr4GtCAVykF4AVJoPbS-f4wQFSTrSbq9fpwMEAoHDKivOAASAIkx2CwRfyRUlW6y2OP2hxOJz4Zwu7Us11u90e1A+VRqOWgeXkimBrR0uWkXKUbhhPTgfRqfI5AoK9lG4yx0zmuMREIqRI2JKVZKOlIE5wglys9LuDyeXH4AA86PAWfAoMEwhFBKo1Hs3cRYvFtEEQuEojE4qhRYrdp0pD87vY4ABvOVjW1wVAQH5QUpaOAAQVEyB4AB5BpYHKoPYG9lgIjBFGoaoabNRxu8KlVFPz8optOyJNLucWA-EyxYZNXUJ3OQVrHGG643GoNB3dFADMQyG1lrZhjG4GRcAB3OD8ChwAC+ZobCeXpCaYD29qTcnc-FdbqTKbTp-GZmcsan4wTMhIyBNMwN4On6-C1Dw-xqBeBgED8MBYAAHAQ74-vaMAplCABStSbAAcgcMSoI+-4wMgqHHu8JClJeGi2N+P77guY5VvwS5GBRR6TuhmFwOGdzUEeFBAA)

```
import * as p from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';


type ErrorHandler = (e: Error, path: string) => any | void;
type ReadFileParams = [string, string, Function];
```

`Object.prototype.toString.call` - надёжнее
+ немного магии

```
const isString = (q: string | any): q is string =>
    '[object String]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(q);
// const isFunction = (q: Function | any): q is Function =>
//  '[object Function]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(q);
const isErrorHandler = (q: ErrorHandler | any): q is ErrorHandler =>
    '[object Function]' === Object.prototype.toString.call(q);
```

тут тоже небольшие правки, используем магию из предыдущего блока

```
export const readFile = (...params: ReadFileParams): object | null => {
    const source: Array<string> = params.filter(isString);
    const errorHandler: ErrorHandler = params.find(isErrorHandler)
        || ((e: Error, path: string) => { throw e; });
    const path = p.resolve(...source);
    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
        return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(e, path);
    }
    return null;
};
```